# Como quebrar linha de uma tabela para dividir em 2 páginas ou mais em um pdf em Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Preciso fazer uma quebra de linha automática na segunda tabela para dividir em 2 folhas do pdf.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

```
Future<Uint8List> getPdf() async {
    List<Sale> sales = report.getSales();

    final pdf = pw.Document();

    final ByteData logoByte =
        await rootBundle.load('images/logo/logo_apollo_pdv.png');
    final Uint8List logo = logoByte.buffer.asUint8List();

    pdf.addPage(
      pw.MultiPage(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        margin: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(24),
        build: (pw.Context context) {
          return [
            pw.Center(
              child: pw.Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  pw.Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        pw.Text(
                          company.getName(),
                          style: pw.TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12, fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        pw.Text(
                          "${company.getAddress()["street"]},${company.getAddress()["number"]}, B. ${company.getAddress()["neighborhood"]}. ${company.getAddress()["city"]} - ${company.getAddress()["uf"]}",
                          style: pw.TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 8,
                            fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal,
                          ),
                        ),
                        pw.Padding(
                          padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                          child: pw.Text(
                            "Contato: ${company.getPhone()}",
                            style: pw.TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 8,
                              fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        pw.Text(
                          "CNPJ: ${company.getCNPJ()}",
                          style: pw.TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 8,
                            fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                  pw.Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        pw.Divider(thickness: 0.4),
                        pw.Text(
                          "RELATÓRIO DE VENDAS",
                          style: pw.TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        pw.Divider(thickness: 0.4),
                      ]),
                  pw.Text(
                    "RESUMO DAS VENDAS",
                    style: pw.TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  pw.ClipRect(),
                  pw.Table(
                    columnWidths: const {
                      0: pw.FixedColumnWidth(150),
                      1: pw.FixedColumnWidth(150),
                      2: pw.FixedColumnWidth(400),
                      3: pw.FixedColumnWidth(200),
                      4: pw.FixedColumnWidth(200),
                    },
                    children: [
                      pw.TableRow(
                        children: [
                          pw.Text(
                            "Data e hora",
                            style: pw.TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 8,
                              fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            textAlign: pw.TextAlign.start,
                          ),
                          pw.Text(
                            "Qtd. de itens",
                            style: pw.TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 8,
                              fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                          pw.Text(
                            "Forma de pagamento",
                            style: pw.TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 8,
                              fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                          pw.Text(
                            "Total da venda",
                            style: pw.TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 8,
                              fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            textAlign: pw.TextAlign.end,
                          ),
                          pw.Text(
                            "Lucro",
                            style: pw.TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 8,
                              fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            textAlign: pw.TextAlign.end,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  pw.Padding(
                    padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                    child: pw.Table(
                      
                      defaultVerticalAlignment:
                          pw.TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                      columnWidths: const {
                        0: pw.FixedColumnWidth(150),
                        1: pw.FixedColumnWidth(150),
                        2: pw.FixedColumnWidth(400),
                        3: pw.FixedColumnWidth(200),
                        4: pw.FixedColumnWidth(200),
                      },
                      border: const pw.TableBorder(
                        // bottom: pw.BorderSide(color: PdfColors.grey300),
                        horizontalInside:
                            pw.BorderSide(color: PdfColors.grey300),
                      ),
                      children: sales.map((sale) {
                        return pw.TableRow(
                          children: [
                            pw.Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, bottom: 4),
                              child: pw.Text(
                                sale.getSale()["date"],
                                style: pw.TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 8,
                                  fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal,
                                ),
                                textAlign: pw.TextAlign.start,
                              ),
                            ),
                            pw.Text(
                              _sumItens(products: sale.getSale()["products"]),
                              style: pw.TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 8,
                                fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal,
                              ),
                              textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                            pw.SizedBox(
                              width: 100,
                              child: pw.Text(
                                paymentForm(
                                    paymentForm: sale.getSale()["paymentForm"]),
                                style: pw.TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 8,
                                  fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal,
                                ),
                                textAlign: pw.TextAlign.start,
                              ),
                            ),
                            pw.Text(
                                Formatters().formatMoneyBRL(
                                    value: sale.getSale()["total"]["total"]),
                                style: pw.TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 8,
                                  fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal,
                                ),
                                textAlign: pw.TextAlign.end),
                            pw.Text(
                                Formatters().formatMoneyBRL(
                                    value: sale.getSale()["profit"]),
                                style: pw.TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 8,
                                  fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                                textAlign: pw.TextAlign.end),
                          ],
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]; // Center
        },
        footer: (context) => pw.Column(
          children: [
            pw.Padding(
              padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
              child: pw.Divider(thickness: 0.4),
            ),
            pw.Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                pw.Image(
                  pw.MemoryImage(logo),
                  height: 16,
                  fit: pw.BoxFit.contain,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    return pdf.save();
  }
```